# SignalR Client not calling Server function

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I have the following javascript which calls the server side signalR hub. The client code

```
// A simple templating method for replacing placeholders enclosed in curly braces.
if (!String.prototype.supplant) {
    String.prototype.supplant = function (o) {
        return this.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g,
            function (a, b) {
                var r = o[b];
                return typeof r === 'string' || typeof r === 'number' ? r : a;
            }
        );
    };
}

$(function () {

    var checker = $.connection.LyncPresenceHub,  //generated client side proxy hub
        available = 'available',
        busy = 'busy',
        $presenceTable = $('lyncPresence'),
        $presenceBody = $presenceTable.find('tbody'),
        rowTemplate = '<tr data-id="{Name}"><td><div class="{Status}"></div></td><td><div class="{Name}"></td></tr>';

    function formatPresence(lyncUser) {
        return $.extend(lyncUser, {
            Name: lyncUser.UserName,
            Status: lyncUser.Presence
        });
    }

    function init() {
        checker.server.GetAllUsers()
            .done(function (lyncUsers) {
                $presenceTable.empty();
                $.each(lyncUsers, function () {
                    var user = formatPresence(this);
                    $presenceBody.append(rowTemplate.supplant(user));
                });
            });
    }

    //Client side hub method which will be called by the server
    checker.client.updateLyncUserPresence = function (LyncUser) {
        var displayPresence = formatPresence(LyncUser);
        $row = $(rowTemplate.supplant(displayPresence));

        $presenceBody.find('tr[data-id=' + LyncUser.Name + ']')
        .replaceWith($row);
    }

    $.connection.hub.start().done(init);
});
```

The SignalR hub code (C#) is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
using Oobe.Bobs.Lync.Models;

namespace xxx  {
    [HubName("LyncPresenceHub")]
    public class LyncPresenceHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly LyncPresenceChecker _lyncpresenceChecker;

        public LyncPresenceHub() : this(LyncPresenceChecker.Instance) { }

        public LyncPresenceHub(LyncPresenceChecker checker)
        {
            _lyncpresenceChecker = checker;
        }
        public IEnumerable<LyncUser> GetAllUsers()
        {
            return _lyncpresenceChecker.GetAllUsers();
        }
    }
}
```

The error i get is as follows. Object does not support property or method "GetAllUsers"

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm !! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `GetAllUsers` doesn't exist in JavaScript. This is because, by default, SignalR takes the first letter and makes it lowercase if it's uppercase. You can override this default behavior by using the `[HubMethodName(string)]` attribute, as shown (and explained) by the MSDN [in this article](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client):

> On the client the proxy name is a camel-cased version of the Hub class name. SignalR automatically makes this change so that JavaScript code can conform to JavaScript conventions.

```
public class ContosoChatHub : Hub
{
    [HubMethodName("NewContosoChatMessage")]
    public void NewContosoChatMessage(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addContosoChatMessageToPage(name, message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or alternatively (and with a few less keystrokes) use a lower-case initial letter on the Javascript side.

Comment: @Corey I'd say that really depends on what you like. I like .NET naming conventions, and so I use the HubMethodName attribute on each method of the hub.

Comment: I prefer the C# capitalization style, but I'm lazy :)